# Unable to select the golang sdk in Intellij IDE

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, go

I am following the following blog to configure my golang environment (OS-X machine):

http://webapp.org.ua/dev/intellij-idea-and-go-plugin/

But, whenever I try to add go sdk (installed at /usr/local/go), it appear blank selection for the SDK.

[image]

Please suggest me, if I am missing something.

Comment: I know it's not what you're asking, but from personal experience the IntelliJ plugin is doesn't work that well. Try LiteIDE or SublimeText with a Go plugin.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer, IntelliJ golang plugin offers `go to declaration` feature, which is not offered by LiteIDE.

Comment: The latest version (25) does have it!

Comment: And it works really well, including the standard library, which doesn't work in Sublime. LiteIDE also has refactor/rename for symbols which is also handy.

Comment: If you are not using the latest alpha versions from [here](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin) then I would recommend you to try that. Also, try to use the path `/YOUR_PATH/libexec`.

Comment: @bamboon I tried LiteIDE, its easy, clean and simple !!

Answer (score 1):

This page lists the SDKs which have already been configured in IntelliJ IDEA. You need to press the "Configure..." button and point the plugin to your SDK installation. Once you do this, it will become available in the SDK list for new project creation.

Comment: I pressed the configure button and selected the go installation path. But I landed back to same page with empty list.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use the following for writing golang application:

1. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/tuGS99f-kqk/Tl5KqNG0js0J
2. https://github.com/visualfc/liteide

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use IDEA with golang, we've made a lot of progress in the past months. Please install the latest release from [github releases](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/releases) and give it a try.

As the name suggests, there are a few issues here and there but it should work much better that the current release of the plugin.

You'll find it a class over the other offerings for writing go apps ;) (disclaimer I'm one of the contributors to the plugin, I'm very biased)